# how to block videos in chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

When I use the selenium for scraping 'twitter.com', I cannot block the auto-played video clips. How can I block the video clips to reduce the memory burden in chromedriver.

here below the code

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" : 2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =   
'C:/Users/aa/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', 
chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In twitter site go to the "profile and settings" and in the content setting uncheck `Video autoplay` checkbox. You can do it automatically with help of Selenium if needed.